# PARSE.COM - Help needed using the AnyMeme cloud code tutorial

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm following the instructions for the AnyMeme tutorial (https://parse.com/tutorials) steps are here https://github.com/ParsePlatform/AnyMeme

I've several questions.

Step 3: When it says install Compass I presume this means into the acutal App i've created? so in my base I'd install it compass create ChristmasApp or does it refer to simply making sure that Compass is installed looally?

Step4: the comand to use is "parse new" (Exclude the "." ?

Step 6: I don't have a cloud/app.js file, all I see there is main.js have I missed something?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Here are my learning's from an afternoon of working this out.

Step3: I'm still not 100% sure on this, will need more study.

Step4: the command should be entered as parse new .

Step 6: This is generated when you complete the "A Dynamic Website" section of the instructions.

I did'n't find the steps that easy to follow, for anyone else that may need this in the future here is what I did in my own words.

This assumes you have the parse console etc functioning correctly.

1: Copy down and extract the AnyMeme github files to your local PC
2: Complete the FB stage
3:Make sure compass is on your pc and working
4:Goto the parse console and change the directory to the location of where you saved the AnyMeme folder
5: type parse new .
6: Delete public/index.html

7: Edit cloud/app.js and put in your Parse Application ID, Parse JavaScript Key, and Facebook Application ID in the key setup section. You can find your app keys in your app settings page under "Application Keys

8:In the parse console type parse deploy
9: complete remaining steps as indicated

Hope this helps save someone else some time ;-)